# How can I see someone's banner?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can see all sorts of details about people in my social window, including their current activity, act progress, their achievements (compared against my own), their heroes, their heroes' equipment, their heroes' skill setup, and a few other player stats, but I can't seem to find a way to see their banner.

Obviously by joining them in a game, I can see their banner in town and when they press <kbd>G</kbd> in said joined game. I'd like a closer look at their banner without the pressure of running quests or holding up the group or things to that effect and so I am interested in **how can I see someone's banner without joining them in a game?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to see another player's banner is by joining a game with them. Simply being in their party in-game (on the menu screen) isn't enough, as only your own banner will be visible. Likewise, you cannot see a player's banner via their profile (though you can see their individual heroes, including what they're wearing).

Once in game, either go to the center of town (where the banner will be flying) or ask the player to show you directly, with "G".

Comment: That's disappointing. I really thought there would be a way to get a good look at their banners, especially without joining them in-game. It's kind of hard to make out the fine details of their designs in the medium-small context of the in-game banner whereas the view is much better in the character select and banner design screens, etc.

Comment: @skovacs1 Well, if nothing else, you can zoom in with `z`!